# How do I reset @Repository after every test in SpringBootTest?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-repositories

I'm trying to put together integration test for my newly created @Repository class, however not having any luck with running all tests together. If I run each test separately - they pass, however if I run the whole test class - two tests fail that attempt to find one row by id in H2 (separate db for testing) and find none.

This is my test class below:

```
package com.vaidas.development.gradecalculatorbackend.repositories;

import com.vaidas.development.gradecalculatorbackend.models.Module;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class ModuleRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ModuleRepository moduleRepository;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void shouldInsertAndFindAll() {
        // GIVEN
        Module module = new Module("Test module", null);
        int count = moduleRepository.findAll().size();

        // WHEN
        moduleRepository.insertModule(module);
        int countAfter = moduleRepository.findAll().size();

        // THEN
        assertEquals(count,countAfter - 1);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void shouldInsertAndFindOne() {
        // GIVEN
        Module module = new Module("Test module", null);
        module = moduleRepository.insertModule(module);

        // WHEN
        Module storedModule = moduleRepository.findOne(module.getId());

        // THEN
        assertEquals(storedModule.toString(), module.toString());
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void shouldUpdate() {
        // GIVEN
        Module module = new Module("Test module", null);
        module = moduleRepository.insertModule(module);
        Module updatedModule = new Module("Test module updated", null);
        updatedModule.setId(module.getId());

        // WHEN
        moduleRepository.updateModule(updatedModule);

        // THEN
        Module foundModule = moduleRepository.findOne(updatedModule.getId());
        assertEquals(foundModule.getName(), updatedModule.getName());
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void shouldDelete() {
        // GIVEN
        Module module = new Module("Test module", null);
        module = moduleRepository.insertModule(module);

        // WHEN
        moduleRepository.deleteModule(module);

        // THEN
        assertEquals(0, moduleRepository.findAll().size());
    }
}
```

What I've tried:

- using @DirtiesContext and @Transactional annotations which I expected to reset the DB content
- using @Before and @After annotations for every test, however it seemed like they acted asynchronously and didn't wait for DB to finish adding/removing instances

The failing tests are:

```
shouldInsertAndFindOne() {
shouldUpdate() {
```

Each of the above throw the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
```

Can someone explain why this would happen and what's the correct way to reset my H2 testing db before each test?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the correct approach, but I usually just add a `repositoryName.deleteAll()` in a `@Before`-annotated method.

```
@Before
public void before() {
    moduleRepository.deleteAll();
    moduleRepository.flush();
}
```

This method will be ran before each of your `@Test`-annotated methods and will ensure that the `moduleRepository` is empty.

Also, that `@Transactional` annotation might be the source of your problem. Have you tried the `@Before` approach without that annotation? Or how about adding a `@Transactional` at the class level?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it turns out I was not retrieving generated key from 'insertModule' method in the Repository. I was assigning returned value of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update method and now I'm using a GeneratedKeyHolder to retrieve this. Stupid mistake of mine. Also, I'm using @Transactional at class-level to rollback the db state to original. Thank you for your input though!